# notify image moved to another folder

Tags: android, image, io, android-gallery

I am a beginner android programmer. I create a project for hiding image. But, I have a problem in my project. Is that:
I use a method to move a photo from the folder `A` to folder `.B`(Here is how I hid it from image gallery) . I am sure that the picture in the folder `A` was deleted and moved to folder `.B`. However, when I open image gallery application I still see this picture is displayed at the folder `A`.

This is method copy picture to folder `.B`:

```
    public static String copyFile(String path) {
        //TO DO: create folder .B

        File pathFrom = new File(path);
        File pathTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.B");
        File file = new File(pathTo, fileToName);

        while (file.exists()) {
            fileToName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            file = new File(pathTo, fileToName);
        }

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(pathFrom);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(data);
            out.write(data);
            in.close();
            out.close();

            return file.getPath();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return "error:" + e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return "error:" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

After copy picture to folder `.B`, I delete this picture in folder `A`:

```
new File(path).delete();
```

So Is there any suggestion for notify for all image gallery know that this picture was moved to another folder or another URI?

**UPDATE: The suggestion for me work fine is:
Before 4.4,you can call this:

sendBroadcast(new `Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));` 
After 4.4,try this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + file)));
```

//the file is new image's path

THank FireSun and everyonce

Comment: if Folder .A and Folder .B lies in the same device use renameTo method to move files from .A to .B

Comment: Ok thanks your suggestion. I will feedback for you after I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After change imgae path,you should notify the gallery to update,so you should send a broadcast to make it.

Before 4.4,you can call this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

After 4.4,try this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + file)));
//the file is new image's path
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I will feedback for you after I tried your suggestion.

Comment: ok I was tried your sugestion and it work fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
pathFrom.delete();
```

Comment: oh... What is defference between `pathFrom.delete();`  and `new File(path).delete();`?

Comment: Please ensure the path exactly, if you create new File, maybe the old "pathFrom" is still exist

Comment: I am sure that the file was copy to folder `.B` and then deleted in folder `A`